# Javascript quiz - trigger modal popup via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to trigger the modal popup manually via Javascript `$("#myModal").modal()` as you can see I inserted it inside this function that analyzes the correct answers and displays a short message yet it did not work.

Here's my code:

```
function showFinalResults() {
          $("#myModal").modal()
          content.innerHTML = "<h3>WELL DONE!</h3>" +
         "<p>You're amazing for taking this quiz. Not many people challenge themselves every now and then. It's always good to stay confident with any challenges that may come your way.</p>" +
          "<h3>" + score + " out of " + quiz.length + " questions, " +
          Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + "%<h3>";
         }
```

Here's the html for the modal:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Modal scripts:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Need more info...  where is the `#myModal` element? Are you using jQuery + Bootstrap? If so, are they getting loaded correctly?

Comment: you suppose to add some model explanation or definition if you use bootstrap you need to initilize the modal

Comment: Also where is the `content` variable defined and is it supposed to be the modal content? You should be setting the contents of the model before you call `.modal()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working code snippet: http://codepen.io/steveharrison/pen/ONgWdL

Your HTML looks correct and `$('#myModal').modal()` is the correct way to trigger the modal. Try using the following JS and see if it works (**edit:** forgot to mention this assumes you have a button element with class `open-modal`, like in above CodePen).

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $('.open-modal').click(function() {
     $('#myModal').modal();
  });
});
```

My guess is that there's an error when you're trying to set the content of the modal... check your console and see if there are any errors.

**Update**

It was not working due to the fact there was a `$` function manually defined which was conflicting with jQuery's `$` fn... and both behaved quite differently (and hence setting, say, `.innerHTML` on such elements like `content` not working as expected). I replaced this `$` fn with regular jQuery selectors, added in the modal HTML he included above, and it's now working (incomplete, but the modal is functional): https://jsfiddle.net/th8dvbo2/3/

Comment: Hmm ok, having a look now and already noticing some potential problems... you're using your own `$` function but also jQuery, and it looks like jQuery is overriding it.

Comment: Also, a problem with `submitBtn`.` (index):201 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: shoot. ok so see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/od6g095L/) see if it will help you get a clearer image of it

Comment: Just forked your fiddle to use jQuery fns and not use your own `$`. The `submitBtn` error is now gone: https://jsfiddle.net/th8dvbo2/

Comment: Now we just need to add the modal.

Comment: can we just add the modal in the fiddle?

Comment: Have updated the fiddle and it's now triggering a modal at the end. It's not setting any of the content of the modal, but you can add that in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107398/discussion-between-steve-harrison-and-martin).

Answer (score 1):

To trigger modal for show hide you can use something like this

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

and

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

so instead of

```
$("#myModal").modal();
```

you can use the above code

Comment: just the same way I have above with `$('#myModal').modal('show');` instead? did not work...

Comment: actually a bit confision is ther, what i understand is you are trying to make some calulation by calling that function and you wanna  show that modal when that function call and change the modal text . am i right ?

Comment: ok then can you provide me the HTML for input field you have mentioned like score and other inputs ?

Comment: FYI `$('#myModal').modal('show')` is equivalent to `$('#myModal').modal()`, just a little more explicit.

Comment: @Steve that's what I thought too